# Customizing Drupal 6 MP3 Player

Tags: 6, theming, media

I'm going to use [MP3 Player](http://drupal.org/project/mp3player) module to play some audio files on drupal 6. as you know it uses [Wordpress MP3 Player](http://wpaudioplayer.com/download) as standalone player and it only has one skin, so how can I obtain more skins or maybe a flash API explaining how to build one?

Comment: I've had great success with http://drupal.org/project/jplayer and you can skin it up all you want if you know php/html/css

Comment: Thanks Jimajamma, If it can be skinned with html/css then it's really great but what about old browsers that doesn't support HTML5, can they display it?

Comment: yep, it will use flash for old browsers, html audio for new ones, and its html/css is pretty stock as well.  of course it "likes" html5 more :)

Comment: Really Thanks, I installed jplayer and it seems not working or maybe I'm missing something: http://s10.postimage.org/9pj5rlcah/jplayer.jpg

Comment: it took a bit of fiddling to work here, so not sure what could be missing or out of whack form that image.  you do have to manually download the actual library from jplayer or happyworm in addition to the module itself (or at least you did back when I installed it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used that particular module, but I used to use the [standalone version](http://wpaudioplayer.com/standalone/) of the WordPress Audio Player a lot.  The player isn't really skinnable in the same way you can skin other Flash components.  There are some JS properties that you can set to change colors and dimenstions.

The [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/361980) for the module claims

> Player can be styled and changed through Drupal admin interface.

so you should visit the settings page to see what you can do.

That said, there are other options you can explore

- [jPlayer](http://drupal.org/project/jplayer)
- [Flowplayer](http://drupal.org/project/flowplayer/)
- [MediaElement](http://drupal.org/project/mediaelement) (Drupal 7 only, though)

Comment: Really Thanks MPD, I actually need to create a custom player. I wish there was a source (.fla) of standalone player so I could build  my own one.